# Listview scroll not working properly it does scroll but not scrolling all the elements of it, it stuck after little bit scroll

Tags: flutter, listview

I am using a package sliding_up_pannel to make my bootomsheet I need to make this scrollable so that is why i am using listview but it is not working properly. At pannel builder property i am giving blur effect and then i am giving my pannel widget which is accepting controller and close pannel call back. in pannel widget at build method i am returning the listview which has different widgets in its children. here is my code of sliding up pannel.

```
               @override
               Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                 return ScreensMainCard(
                   margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 105),
                   child: SlidingUpPanel(
                    //TODO: Add Maps Here
                    body: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30)),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage("images/maps.PNG"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                          ),
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * closedPanel,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30)),
                panelBuilder: (controller) => BackdropFilter(
               filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20, sigmaY: 20),
                child: PanelWidget(
                  closePanel: closePanel,
                   controller: controller,
                                 ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                         }
```

here is code of my pannel widegt.

```
             Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                                   return ListView(
                                   shrinkWrap: true,
                                   physics:  const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                   controller: controller,
                                   padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                   children: [

                                       SizedBox(height: 10),
                                       buildDragHandle(),
                                       SizedBox(height: 40),
                                       Center(
                                         child: Text(
                                                    'About',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 
                                               FontWeight.bold),
                                                            ),
                                                           ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                                        Gauges(),
                                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {},
                                            child: Container(
                                            margin:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 20, 25),
                                            height: 50,
                                            decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                                         borderRadius: 
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                                          color: kViveLaCarViolet,
                                                              ),
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                           child:  Text(
                                                    "RESERVATION",
                                           style: kLoginRegisterScreenButtonTextStyle,
                                                                             ),
                                                                          ),
                                                                        ),
                                                    LockUnlockButton(),
                                                    Container(
                                         margin:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                                         height: 140,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                                  color: kViveLaCarWhite,
                                         ),
                                        ],
                                     );
                                    }
```